# A Cryptic Integration Crossword

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-crosswords

A little while ago I started getting into cryptic crosswords (after several false starts over the years) and have started enjoying them and doing them on the regular.

I thought I would try creating one myself. Specifically one focussed on Software Integration so I could use it as a way of getting some colleagues interested in them as well. Then I thought I may as well share it here too, as who doesn't love a nerdy crossword!

Some disclaimers:

- Knowledge tag because it is industry specific. If you have a background in computer science or software architecture you should be all good to go - and probably find it quite easy.
- I'm not 100% sure every clue strictly conforms to the Cryptic Crossword structure. Would appreciate any feedback in this regard (and overall feedback in general).
- The grid is not symetrical. That went into the too-hard-basket.

Solve the grid on [Crossshare](https://crosshare.org/crosswords/cNw01qryRxuABl3GwAPQ/integration-cryptic) or print it out below and solve it over a nice cup of tea.

[image: Integration Cryptic Crossword]

| # | Across | # | Down |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | High level design is like a wild charcuterie with tea. (12) | 2 | Travel 100 pastures north, behold, a tidy architecture. (5) |
| 8 | Notification for the first lady of Northern Territories. (5) | 3 | Orientating another way to achieve system connectivity. (11) |
| 10 | Line up for message transport. (5) | 4 | Stop! Remove Steve's Top! I see; what a group of events! (5) |
| 12 | Sewer, you say? Initially some obscure application, then an architectural style. (1,1,1) | 5 | Ask about repeating an adventure. (7) |
| 13 | Ready made software for sleepy children. (1,1,1,1) | 6 | Sleepy API style found in pure stallion. (4) |
| 14 | Lesser vices include an integration application. (7) | 7 | Era of untidiness? Send some data! (7) |
| 15 | Kill your short mother with a bounded context! (6) | 9 | A hog chows down lane producing a fancy reverse proxy. (3,7) |
| 17 | A green vehicle connects public and private clouds. (6) | 11 | Openers messed up to mostly reply. (8) |
| 19 | Send the farm building onto the stage! 'Etty's loudly orchestrating containers. (10) | 12 | A small Holy man with 500 sheets of paper delivers notifications down a river. (6) |
|  |  | 13 | See I see; dee I say! Deployment automation is the way! (1,1,1,1) |
|  |  | 16 | Atop a charged atom, find a layered pattern which will make you cry. (5) |
|  |  | 18 | Interconnected services hidden in lame shop. (4) |

Comment: Well done!  I see some of the answers.  Knowledge tag is definitely important.  If no one puts together a solution I will when I have more spare time.

Comment: This is a fun puzzle (for me, a programmer). I'm 2/3 done. I'll keep going with it, and if nobody else does, I'll post a partial answer. One feedback is that many words don't link to many other words, so solving a clue doesn't gain you much for other clues. But not sure I could have done any better.

Comment: Is the enumeration or the diagram incorrect for 9D?

Comment: @LeppyR64 It should be 3,7.

Comment: Ah you are right - can't count apparently. I will update this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the completed grid. Thanks juicifer for getting the last one for me!

> [image]

Clue explanations:

Across:

> 1. High level design is like a wild **charcuterie** with **tea** - anagram.
>  8. Notification for the first lady of Northern Territories. [Eva Lawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eva_Lawler) is the Chief Minister of the Northern Territories in Australia. **EVE** + **NT** for  Northern Territories.
>  10. Line up for message transport - not really cryptic but line up is a synonym of queue.
>  12. Sewer, you say? Initially some obscure application, then an architectural style - I guess **SOA** could be pronounced like **SEWER**?
>  13. Ready made software for sleepy children - **COTS** is an acronym for Custom Off The Shelf, i.e. ready made software. Kids sleep in cots.
>  14. Les **ser vice**s include an integration application - answer contained in clue.
>  15. Kill your short mother with a bounded context! - To do someone in is to kill them. Ma is short for mother. **DO** + **MA** + **IN**.
>  17. A green vehicle connects public and private clouds - a hybrid vehicle is considered green.
>  19. Send the farm building onto the stage! 'Etty's loudly orchestrating containers - Not entirely sure, but **bern** sounds like barn, and **Etty's** could be written **etes**.

Down:

> 2. Travel 100 pastures north, behold, a tidy architecture - 100 is roman numerals for **C**, a **LEA** is a pasture, **N** for North.
>  3. Orientating another way to achieve system connectivity - not really cryptic, but integration could be a form of orientating.
>  4. Stop! Remove Steve's Top! I see; what a group of events! - Steve's top is **S**, remove that from **Stop** gives **TOP**, plus "I see" = **IC**.
>  5. Ask about repeating an adventure - Repeating **RE** adventure **QUEST**.
>  6. Sleepy API style found in pu **re st** allion. Answer contained in clue.
>  7. Era of untidiness? Send some data! - Untidiness = **MESS**, Era = **AGE**.
>  9. A hog chows down lane producing a fancy reverse proxy - A hog = **A PIG**, chows down = **ATE**, lane = **WAY**.
>  11. **Openers** messed up to mostly reply - anagram (mostly, we need an extra S).
>  12. A small Holy man with 500 sheets of paper delivers notifications down a river - holy man is "saint", shortened to **ST**, a **REAM** is 500 sheets of paper.
>  13. See I see; dee I say! Deployment automation is the way! See I see; dee = **CICD**. Continuous integration, continuous deployment.
>  16. Atop a charged atom, find a layered pattern which will make you cry - Atop = **ON**, charged atom = **ION**.
>  18. Interconnected services hidden in la **me sh** op - answer contained in clue.

Thanks for the fun puzzle!

Comment: Looking pretty good, only one which isn't quite right at this stage - 12 across. Probably a more niche one...

Comment: @Johnson I think I fixed 12a, and got two more clues. I'm only missing 4d now.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I think 4d is rot13(FGBC - F + VP)

Comment: Congrats! Great work! You have the completed grid, and nailed most of the explanations. Just a couple of comments for some: 8a: (Gur svefg ynql vagrqrq jnf whfg gur Ovoyvpny Rir, jvgu Abegurea Greevgbevrf cebivqvat gur AG) 12a (Frjre - nf va fbzrbar jub frjf - sbe cebahapvngvba checbfrf.) 19a (Fraq gur snez ohvyqvat bagb gur fgntr = "Phr Onea". "Ybhqyl" pyhrf ubzbcubarf. Phr Onea 'Rgglf.) 3d (Bevragngvat vf na nantenz bs vagrtengvba - urapr "Bevragngvat nabgure jnl").

Comment: @Johnson Thanks for the clarifications. Quite crazy that the first lady happens to have almost the same name as the Chief Minister. Really enjoyed your puzzle.